# Why were tables built into ipchains?

Tags: iptables

Why are tables built into `ipchains`? What was the benefit of adding tables to `ipchains`? Is there a simple scenario that would illustrate how tables are used to increase performance or offer some other benefit?

Comment: I'm not sure if the question was understood the way I intended to ;) Basically, I wanted to know, why tables, such as raw, mangle, nat, filter were added to ipchains. The examples that Chris S and cjc provided explain very well, how one can use user-defined chains with iptables (I've actually learned new things thanks to their posts). From what I've read so far, user-defined chains are not tables. Maybe I should create a new question about iptables tables. Of course I may be wrong as I'm new to the iptables topic.

Comment: I don't understand the question, with or without your comment. The built-in tables control various aspects of how packets are handled; [this chart](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) (courtesy of [artistoex](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5766/artistoex)) shows how they're used. This isn't a matter of performance, it's part of what `iptables` is meant to control.

Comment: I've asked the question to understand, what are iptables tables in relation to iptables chains. Are tables sets of chains or are tables some other entities that share common features with chains? If tables are sets of chains, why it looks like there are 4 tables in the OUTPUT chain on this diagram: [link](http://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/images/tables_traverse.jpg).

Comment: I've asked the question to understand, what are iptables tables in relation to iptables chains. Are tables sets of chains or are tables some other entities that share common features with chains? If tables are sets of chains, why it looks like there are 4 tables in one chain on this diagram: [link](http://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/images/tables_traverse.jpg). From what I've read so far, the tables are in deed sets of chains. So, to narrow down the q, what benefits iptables gets from implementing tables? What would happen if the tables weren't implemented?Hv sth to do wth ipt modules?

Comment: Good question. "Tables" appear prominently in the user docs, but it's not clear how they matter and why a user would need to know. In fact, packets travel through chains, but the order in which these chains are linked does not correspond to those "tables"; if that were the case, all chains in one table (say, `mangle`) would have to come first, then all in the next one, and so on. - It seems to be all about chains; tables seem to serve no clear purpose. Are they an implementation detail leaked to user docs? Is that because the predecessor was called `ipchains` and there had to be a difference?

Answer (score 3):

```
iptables -N dmzrules
iptables -A dmzrules -p TCP --dport 22  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A dmzrules -p TCP --dport 80  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A dmzrules -p TCP --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A dmzrules -p UDP --dport 53  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A dmzrules -p UDP --dport 123 -j ACCEPT


iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.0.91.0/24    -j dmzrules
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.22.0/24 -j dmzrules
iptables -A FORWARD -s 172.16.33.0/24  -j dmzrules
```

So, in the above example, you don't have to write rules for the same set of allowed UDP/TCP ports over and over again for the allowed networks.  So, you have 9 lines instead of 15.  There should be some performance improvement since each incoming packet doesn't have to try matching on 15 rules.  Instead, a packet will be matched those 3 INPUT rules, and if there's a match on the source IP, it will try matching on the 4 rules in the dmzrules table.

I think if you're using iptables for a single box, it may be less useful to use tables.  You can probably just enumerate the allowed ports in one swoop, though Chris's point about black/white lists is something to keep in mind, i.e., you can update this list without mucking with the main set of rules.

Answer (score 2):

"tables" were included because the concept carried over to ipchains from when Linux used BSD's IPFW firewall. They make it easy to apply one or more rules to a set of IPs that should administratively be treated the same.

The most common place I see them is when using black or white lists. You might be using fail2ban to automatically block IPs that are "attacking" your server, adding them to a naughty table instead of creating a rule for each IP keeps things clean. Similarly you might have a set of "administrative" machines on your network with diverse IPs, you could add those to a table then write a single rule that allows them to SSH into your server.