# How to make sense of an iptables chain configuration in OpenWrt

Tags: iptables, openwrt, router

This is about how to make sense of the *chains* found in the `iptables` default configuration on a typical home router running OpenWrt (a stripped down Linux for router devices), but which ultimately may not be specific to that particular system.

Let's focus on the `INPUT` main chain here, and disregard `FORWARD` and `OUTPUT` from the same [*table*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27341/27995), as well as `PREROUTING` and `POSTROUTING` from the `nat` table.

Doing an `iptables -L -t filter` shows a large number of rules. I have rearranged the output below to make it less intimidating, and in an attempt to pinpoint the parts that hamper my understanding.

There are three built-in chains in the `filter` table, which appear at the top of the output. (I specified `-v` because I find it [less confusing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52205/27995).)

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 1260  133K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    8   544 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere
  787 41632 syn_flood  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN
13012 1249K input_rule  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
13012 1249K input      all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD … # not considering this chain here
Chain OUTPUT …  # not considering either
```

As you can see, I snipped the chains referenced from `FORWARD` and `OUTPUT` in order to focus on `INPUT`. (I could have chosen any of the other two as they are built up in a similiar manner.)

`INPUT` has a policy of `ACCEPT`, and it specifies five rules. The first three ones are clear to me. First, accept stuff that is "established" or "related". (For example, accept the response from an HTTP or DNS request I made.) Seconds, accept everything going to the loopback device (`127.0.0.1`). (This may only come from localhost itself, and I do want that to work. Wouldn't make sense otherwise.) Third, have a synflood protection. (Which protects against a certain kind of attack.)

```
Chain syn_flood (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  787 41632 RETURN     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN limit: avg 25/sec burst 50
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

But then, there are two rules branching into two chains called `input` and `input_rule`, and the question is, why are there two of them, and which one are you supposed to use for what?

Let's drill down the jump stack of those rules.

```
Chain input_rule (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

There's nothing in here yet. It is meant for me to add rules. But what kind of rules?

```
Chain input (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 6315  482K zone_lan   all  --  br-lan any     anywhere             anywhere
 6697  767K zone_wan   all  --  pppoe-wan any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Okay, this one does have stuff, jumping further down into LAN and WAN, which makes sense for a home router.

```
Chain zone_lan (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 6315  482K input_lan  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 6315  482K zone_lan_ACCEPT  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Chain zone_wan (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:bootpc
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request
 6697  767K input_wan  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
 6697  767K zone_wan_REJECT  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

As you can see, each one of those rules jumps further down the stack to more user-defined rules.

```
Chain input_lan (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain zone_lan_ACCEPT (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    4  1322 ACCEPT     all  --  any    br-lan  anywhere             anywhere
 6315  482K ACCEPT     all  --  br-lan any     anywhere             anywhere
```

What is the purpose of `input_lan`? The other one is probably to accept packets, but it makes me wonder … the policy for `INPUT` is `ACCEPT`, so why repeat `ACCEPT` here?

Now, input from WAN. If you scroll up you can see that some UDP and ICMP stuff is accepted. This is for DHCP and, basically, `ping`. That much is clear. What is less clear, again, is the partially empty stuff following those rules:

```
Chain input_wan (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Same question as for `input_lan`.

```
Chain zone_wan_REJECT (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 reject     all  --  any    pppoe-wan  anywhere             anywhere
 6697  767K reject     all  --  pppoe-wan any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Okay, that is input from WAN (not established or related), and yes, we probably want to reject it, and now there are two kinds of rejection here, one closing the socket (`tcp-reset`) for TCP connection attempts, and another one via ICMP reply (`icmp-port-unreachable`) for ICMP messages (think `ping`).

```
Chain reject (5 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  595 31817 REJECT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            reject-with tcp-reset
 4858  582K REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

This last one is a catch-all. So nothing will get accepted here.

Finally, here's a list of other chains found in the `filter` table that aren't referenced from the built-in `INPUT` chain in the `net` table. Just for completeness, and to see that they seem to have analogous constructs.

```
# other chains, not reached from the INPUT chain, so truncated and moved here
Chain forward (1 references)
Chain forwarding_lan (1 references)
Chain forwarding_rule (1 references)
Chain forwarding_wan (1 references)
Chain nat_reflection_fwd (1 references)
Chain output (1 references)
Chain output_rule (1 references)
Chain reject (5 references)
Chain zone_lan_DROP (0 references)
Chain zone_lan_REJECT (1 references)
Chain zone_lan_forward (1 references)
Chain zone_wan_ACCEPT (2 references)
Chain zone_wan_DROP (0 references)
Chain zone_wan_forward (1 references)
```

So, well. Sorry for this long post. There were a couple questions along the way. I don't know how to put this in an easier or shorter way. This `iptables` configuration is not exactly easy to grasp because there are unclear details spread about here and there. Hope you can clarify this and explain the underlying rationale. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the firewall is generated from some higher-level configuration file on openwrt. As a lot of different possibilities need to be supported, the actually generate rules are not optimized and can contain therefore unnecessary/unused/empty chains. See OpenWRT's [wiki article](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/firewall) for more details.

To answer some of your questions

- why is "input_rule" empty

  As your mentioned it could be a place where the user easily can insert custom rules. Another possibility is that "input" was originally "input_rule" and that "input_rule" is still created for backward compatibility with old scripts.
- What is the purpose of input_lan/input_wan?

  There you can block traffic from internal hosts on the LAN to the router (for example to protect its configuration interface) or enable access from outside.
- The default for INPUT is ACCEPT, so why repeat ACCEPT here?

  As you correctly noticed, this is not necessary here. But as zone_lan_REJECT exists, it seems that the script want to be independent from the policy.

Comment: Thank you, jofel. I had seen that page before but then one of the developers told me that: ["All switch vlan, swconfig and similar documentation does not apply to your device."](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=40637) I had spent quite some time reading docs and trying to make sense of it … I'm struggling understanding some basics about OpenWrt, like [what are all those interfaces good for](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=40508)? Some stuff might be specific to OpenWrt, or to a router device - unfortunately it is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

This is a clear separation of concerns.  The rules for access to and from the WAN should be different from those for the LAN.

The default configuration does not provide accept rules for services not necessarily offered on your network.  Typically, most users should offer no services to the Internet.  Adding appropriate rules to the appropriate rule sets will enable services.  The OpenWrt Web interface should provide the assistance via drop downs.

The [Shorewall Basic Two-Interace Firewall](http://www.shorewall.net/two-interface.htm) documentation should give you a good understanding of what is and should be happening.  It is possible to replace the OpenWrt firewall with a Shorewall-lite firewall, but for a basic firewall the existing firewall will do.  Some of packages will assume they are working with the default firewall and will take some work if you aren't.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. I do understand about the rules being different for LAN and WAN, and about the default configuration being restrictive. That much is clear. What is not so clear is how to work with this iptables chain configuration, where to put what and why. Relying on a web interface, hmm, okay; a bit unsatisfying. - Shorewall: Sounds like a meta-configuration on top of iptables. The docs don't make it entirely clear at first glance, though. - Both OpenWrt and Shorewall have »zones«. Sounds like helper config stuff to avoid redundant rules in chains. - Doc situation could be improved.

Comment: @Lumi Shorewall is an tool to build rules for iptables.  It uses the same model for rule sets as I see in your description above.  I pointed to the documentation as it describes this sort of configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [a tool precisely for this task](https://github.com/native-api/iptables-list). It reformats `iptables -S` output into a tree of chains as they are being applied.

By analyzing its output, I deduced that `_rule` chains are intended for manually-added rules.

The tool is also useful for rule diagnostics: if you reset rule counters, make a network test, then feed it the output with packet counters, you will be able to see which way(s) in the tree your test traffic went.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with jofel.

input_rule, input_lan and input_wan is for backward compatibility with old scripts.

For a better packet statistics to new UCI, put your rules in zone_lan and zone_wan should be better.
And also，the zone_lan_accept there probably used for in and out packet count.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the openwrt iptables rules are well organized.

Take delegate_input for example(other chain has similar structure):

- two ACCEPTs:accept lo and tcp RELATED,ESTABLISHED traffic
- syn_flood: drop syn flood traffic
- input_rule: deal with input from BOTH lan and wan traffic
- zone_lan: deal with input ONLY from lan, will ACCEPT traffic without match
- zone_wan: deal with input ONLY from wan, will reject traffic without match